# get max serial no. according to sum of its corresponding amount

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table with data as follows:

```
s_no  amount
1      500
2      500
3      500
4      500
5      500
```

I need a query to find the max(s_no) according to the sum(amount)
For e.g. when sum(amount)<=1600 i need 4 as result.**I can get the desired output by using cursor but it would be easier if i could use query.**. I tried a query as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(s_no) from table HAVING SUM(amount)<=1600
```

But it doesn't work. I would appreciate any kind of help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  min(s_no)   as s_no

from   (select  s_no 
               ,sum(amount) over (order by s_no) as running_total 

        from    mytable
        ) t 

where   running_total > 1600
```

Comment: this works fine in sql 2012 but it says Incorrect syntax near 'order'. in sql 2008.

Comment: I worked on this but only found the `over` solution after seeing the answers here. Anyway, my final effort is [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/607845/query-for-q159115?MaxAggRep=1000000 "using SEDE").

Answer (score 5):

Another way – that works in versions prior to 2012 – is to use a recursive CTE.

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/MKUC98636):

```
WITH ct AS
  ( SELECT TOP (1) s_no, amount, running_total = amount
    FROM tableX
    ORDER BY s_no

    UNION ALL

    SELECT n.s_no, n.amount, n.amount + n.previous_total
    FROM 
      ( SELECT t.s_no, t.amount, previous_total = ct.running_total,
               rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.s_no) 
        FROM ct
          JOIN tableX AS t
            ON t.s_no > ct.s_no
        WHERE ct.running_total < 1600 
      ) AS n
    WHERE n.rn = 1
  )
SELECT *
FROM ct 
WHERE running_total >= 1600 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) ;          -- no limit on recursion
```

The CTE's anchor (the UNION ALL's first leg) selects only the first row. Then in each iteration the CTE's recursive part (the second leg) selects the next row and computes the running total until the sum is 1600 or more.

The `ROW_NUMBER()` trick and subquery is to overcome the limitation that `TOP` is not allowed in the recursive parts of CTEs.

Answer (score 3):

```
select      t1.s_no

from                    mytable as t1

            join        mytable as t2

            on          t2.s_no <= t1.s_no

group by    t1.s_no
           ,t1.amount

having      sum(t2.amount) - t1.amount <= 1600
        and sum(t2.amount)             >  1600
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select  s_no 

from   (select  s_no
               ,sum(amount) over 
                (
                    order by    s_no 
                    rows        between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                ) as running_total_1

               ,sum(amount) over 
                (
                    order by    s_no   
                    rows        between unbounded preceding and current row
                ) as running_total_2

        from    mytable
        ) t

where   running_total_1 <= 1600 
    and running_total_2 >  1600
```

Comment: SQL Server 2008 does not have a full support for windowing (`over (... rows/range ...)`)

Comment: do we really need 3 separate answers for the question? I can understand 2 answers (one for 2008 and one for 2012+ versions). But 3?

Comment: @TypoCubeᵀᴹ - Different answers with different logic and different characteristics . If there were given by different people you wouldn't have a problem with this.

Comment: See the discussion: [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice) I don't have any problem with multiple answers, if they are sufficiently different (although I personally prefer to answer in one). If you think that the 3 answers are different, it's fine by me.